# convert an array of variable names into strings js

Tags: javascript

```
var a = "aa", b= "bb",c ="cc", d="dd", e="ee";
array = [a,b,c,d,e] // outputs ["aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee"];
```

However is there a possibility in javascript to convert the variables (a, b,c,d,e) into strings?

Like: "a", "b", "c", "d", "e"??

P.S: the array values could be dynamic as well or more than the length mentioned above.

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: They already are strings. What are you asking? Do you mean the variable *names*?

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: sorry, my bad, yes I meant the variable names into string =, updated the Question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this

```js
var a = "aa", b= "bb",c ="cc", d="dd", e="ee";
var array = [a,b,c,d,e];
({a,b,c,d,e} = array)
var keys = Object.keys({a,b,c,d,e});
console.log(keys)
console.log(array)
```

Comment: sorry that may not work...same thing I mentioned above for @Nenad's answer. ({a,b,c,d,e} ) are just examples, the values could be more than 10 or 50, in this case ({a,b,c,d,e,......)} might not be faesible.

Comment: maybe If you explain the complete use case, we could help, like why do you need to do this, how its being used

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with ES6 shorthand property names and return array of strings.

```js
let a = "aa", b= "bb",c ="cc", d="dd", e="ee";
let strings = Object.keys({a, b, c, d, e});
console.log(...strings)
```

Comment: that would ideally work if there was a fixed length of values in that array. My array could have 10 -20 items in it. Object.keys(a,b,c,....) might make it cumberosme to add every variable value to convert it to string..?

Comment: Why not just use object instead of an array, then you have key and value?

Comment: I tried this: Object.assign({}, array);, //outputs to: {0: "aa", 1: "bb", 2: "cc", 3: "dd", 4: "ee"}  it will still give me the values and not the variable names.